# c# - selenium Nunit testing - how to do validation check for signup form

Tags: validation, selenium, nunit

Hi I am trying to test this online signup form. I have created a test but I would like to do a validation check on each field,

e.g. 
For Name field

driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).SendKeys("Clayton")

I would like to try different text/number/characters and see what goes through and what fails. 
Is there any way i could do this?
please see the codes.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class loop
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://something.com/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheSignupTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys("something");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("something");
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.btn.small")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav2")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("upload-file")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).SendKeys("00"); 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReferenceNumberPrefix")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReferenceNumberPrefix")).SendKeys("00");
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();
        }
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
        {
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert)
                {
                    alert.Accept();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            }
            finally
            {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good start would be to transform your test into a parameterized test and use the [TestCaseAttribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.6.3).

Your test could then look like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCase("Clayton", "abc", true)]
[TestCase("Clayton", "def", false)]
public void TheSignupTest(string username, string password, bool isAccepted)
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("UserName")).SendKeys(username);
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys(password);
    driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input.btn.small")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("nav2")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("upload-file")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("Name")).SendKeys("00"); 
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReferenceNumberPrefix")).Clear();
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ReferenceNumberPrefix")).SendKeys("00");
    driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit")).Click();

    if (isAccepted)
    {
        Assert.That(driver.Url, Is.EqualTo(baseURL + "/PageWhereClientIsRedirectedToAfterSuccessfulLogin"));
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.That(driver.FindElement(By.Name("ErrorBox")).Text, Is.EqualTo("Login failed"));
    }
}
```

The test cases are defined using the `TestCaseAttribute`:

```
[TestCase("Clayton", "abc", true)]
[TestCase("Clayton", "def", false)]
```

So you have two test cases in your test runner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am sorry I am new to this would you be able to define bit more. Do I need TastCaseAttribute after the  public void TheSignupTest()?

Comment: is there any possible i could have your email? so you could help me in this matter. that would be kind of you.

Comment: No. Otherwise I'd have to bill you for this. ;-)